The period of simple harmonic motion
Am i understanding this correctly?
The harmonic oscillation of an object can be seen as the movement in the y direction along a circular path. So the time for one revolution around the circle will be the same as one oscillation. Therefore we say that the period can be seen as the time it takes for the object to complete one oscillation.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

SHM oscillator is such in which restoring force is proportional to the deflection from equilibrium position. It has nothing to do with periodical path shape. If this condition is met, periodic path can take any form, like $\infty$ or more complex ones,- check Lissajous figures which is type of CHM (complex harmonic motion).

Your description is correct as long as you qualify it with one dimensional SHM. As pointed out in other comments, you can have SHM in more than one dimension, and with different periods in each dimension.

Yes, that statement is correct. There's a connection between simple harmonic motion (SHM) and uniform circular motion. Here's how to visualize it:
Imagine an object moving at a constant speed along a circular path.
Shine a light on this object from the side, casting its shadow onto a wall.
Then
the shadow of the object will move back and forth along a straight line on the wall. This back-and-forth motion of the shadow is simple harmonic motion.
The position of the shadow at any given time corresponds to the y-component of the object's position on the circular path,  the velocity of the shadow corresponds to the y-component of the object's velocity, and similarly for acceleration.
The mathematical equations describing the motion of the shadow (SHM) and the y-component of the object's circular motion are identical.
